# MySQL sorting wrongly with danish characters

Tags: mysql, character-encoding

Danish alphabetization requires abc... to come before æ, ø and å. In my MySQL database, when I sort alphabetically, it comes out as

```
Øresund
Åse
Alfa
```

which is strange.

Server connection collation is utf8_general_ci
Database collation is latin1_swedish_ci
Table collation is utf8_danish_ci
Column collation is utf8_danish_ci

Shouldn't setting a collation on the table/column overwrite collations on a higher level?

My website is all UTF8, and when I input text from the website, it comes fine out again. But when I look at the text in phpmyadmin, characters are displayed wrongly.

I've pasted the contents of the file, editschool.php, here: http://pastebin.com/pv8u0BDj

Comment: Database collation has higher priority than table or column collation.Take a backup and ALTER db collation

Comment: *"when I look at the text in phpmyadmin, characters are displayed wrongly"* - Do you mean that what was entered into the website as 'Øresund' shows up in phpMyAdmin as 'Ã˜resund' (or something like that)?

Comment: @Mihai I was afraid of that. Time to think...

Comment: @GordThompson Exactly! But it looks allright, when it comes out on a php page...

Comment: @Mihai But I have other tables in my database, which are not in Danish...

Comment: It sounds like PHP is converting Unicode input into Latin1 characters before storing them in the table. If your code is not doing that explicitly (e.g., using `utf8_decode()` or similar) then it may be happening implicitly. Make sure that your PHP source files are saved with utf-8 encoding (not ANSI, ASCII, etc.). If the problem persists then code up an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in PHP that shows how you save and retrieve the text, then [edit] your question to include that code.

Comment: Change your mysql client,phpmyadmin is generally buggy

Comment: @GordThompson My files are saved as UTF8, but I didn't use utf8_encode and _decode. I do now. Something as changed. The html output is still fine (as it should be), but the text in phpmyadmin has changed. Where before,

    Ørestad

was saved as

    Ã¸restad

it now reads

    ÃƒÂ˜restad

So this is the result of utf8_encoding stuff before putting it in the DB. And the sorting is still off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to make it work. One or both of these solved the problem:

<strike>1. Adding mysqli_set_charset($connection,"UTF8"); to the top of my file,</strike>

2. Forcing my FTP client to upload as UTF-8.

Edit: I now consider option 2 of the above by far the most probable, which is why I striked option 1 through.

Comment: Remove `utf8_decode`.  If you are getting `ÃƒÂ˜restad`, you have Mojibake and don't have ut8 everywhere.